# What does :: mean in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have seen a syntax like

```
<a href={{ ::something}}>some other thing</a>
```

What is that double colon for? What happens if it is removed?

Comment: It's used to remove a watcher from `something`. So if you update the variable `something` you won't see a noticeable change in the DOM

Comment: thanks, and what does the watcher do?(really new to angular)

Comment: It will 'watch' for any changes to that variable. If you change the `something` variable in that scope then it will change everywhere you've referenced it

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`::` is used for one-time binding. The expression will stop recalculating once they are stable, i.e. after the first digest.

So any updates made to `something` will not be visible.

Comment: try this link this link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCYHSRR0ACH3

Comment: And from angularjs documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

Answer (score 10):

It's used to bind model from your controller to view only. It will not update your controller model if you change this from your view. It means it's used to achieve one time binding.

**Example**

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.label = 'Some text';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">  
    <div>{{::label}}</div> // this will print `Some text` on load
    <div>{{label}}</div> // this will too print `Some text` on load
    <br />
    <button ng-click="label='IUpdateLabelFromHtml'">Change label</button>
  </body>
 </html>
```

When we change label meaning when we click on Change label link, it will update only second text i.e. binded without `::` operator.

Read this for more details [One way binding](http://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/)

Answer (score 2):

It means that the scope item "something" has one time binding associated to it. Thus should the item change in the controller the change will not be applied.

[This is a good article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html) on watchers and one time bindings