# What does double colon before expression variable do in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs, what is a double colon `::` before an expression variable, and  what is the difference between `{{ firstName }}` and `{{ ::firstName }}`?

Comment: Google "one time binding"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does :: mean in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201325/what-does-mean-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Taken from: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135

It reads:

> One-time binding syntax `{{ ::value }}`
>
> AngularJS dropped a really interesting feature recently in the beta
>   version of 1.3.0: the ability to render data once and let it persist
>   without being affected by future Model updates. This is fantastic news
>   for developers highly concerned with performance! Before this update,
>   we’d typically render a value in the DOM like so:
>
> ```
>  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
> ```
>
> With the new one-time binding syntax, we introduce a double-colon
>   before our value:
>
> ```
>  <h1>{{ ::title }}</h1>
> ```
>
> Angular processes the DOM as usual and once the value has been
>   resolved it removes the particular property from its internal
>   `$$watchers` list. What does this mean for performance? A lot! This is a
>   fantastic addition to helping us fine tune our applications.
>
> It’s known that Angular becomes slower with around 2,000 bindings due
>   to the process behind dirty-checking. The less we can add to this
>   limit the better, as bindings can add up without us really noticing
>   it!
>
> Using the single binding syntax is easy and most importantly fast.
>   The syntax is clear and concise, and a real benefit to lowering the
>   `$$watcher` overhead. The less work Angular has to do, the more
>   responsive our applications will become.