# ngRepeat- Whenever i click on the "All" option in drop-down , browser become unresponsive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angularjs version 1.3.

With the help of ngRepeat, i want to display around 9000 data at a time when i click on All option in the dropdown.

On click of ALL we are not hitting the database again since we are taking the entire dataset at once at the time of page load.

[image]

But as soon as I click on All option, the entire page freezes for a few mins.

Data size varies from 9000 to 11000 rows.

Is there any way I can stop it from being unresponsive?

Code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in (filteredSearchItems = (fullSearchItems | filter:getSearchObject()) | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | startFrom:viewState.currentPage*viewState.pageSize | limitTo:viewState.pageSize)"   ng-click="selectItem(item)" style="cursor: pointer;" id="{{item.Id}}">
                    <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Type}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Region}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Location}}</td>......</tr>
```

Comment: you can have a look at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

Comment: If the data is changing, then try using the one time binding syntax `::` before your item? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35384379/1663821