# AngularJs: Directive trigger when value change

Tags: angularjs, exif

I am a newbie of angularjs using version 1.6.4. I am using this directive [Angular Fix Image Orientation Directive](https://github.com/czarpino/angular-fix-image-orientation). But the problem is sometimes the directive trigger before imageUrl model update. How can i trigger again when value update, so that image render again. I think i need to use $watch but i don't know how to use here. Really need help.

```
<img img-fix-orientation="imageUrl" ng-src="{{ imageUrl }}">
```

img-fix-orientation directive:

```
(function (angular, EXIF) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("cp.ng.fix-image-orientation", []).directive('imgFixOrientation', [orient]);

    /**
     * Directive definition.
     * 
     * @returns {object}
     */
    function orient() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                'imgFixOrientation': '='
            },
            link: linkLogic
        };

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * 
         * @param {object} scope
         * @param {object} element
         * @param {object} attrs
         * @returns {undefined}
         */
        function linkLogic(scope, element, attrs) {
            var imageUrl = scope.imgFixOrientation;

            if (0 === imageUrl.indexOf('data:image')) {
                var base64 = imageUrl.split(',')[1];
                var exifData = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(base64ToArrayBuffer(base64));
                reOrient(parseInt(exifData.Orientation || 1, 10), element);
            }
            else {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", imageUrl, true);
                xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
                xhr.onload = function(e) {
                    var arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(this.response);
                    var exifData = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(arrayBuffer.buffer);
                    reOrient(parseInt(exifData.Orientation || 1, 10), element);
                };
                xhr.send();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Convert base64 string to array buffer.
         * 
         * @param {string} base64
         * @returns {object}
         */
        function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
            var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
            var len = binaryString.length;
            var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
                bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            return bytes.buffer;
        }

        /**
         * Reorient specified element.
         * 
         * @param {number} orientation
         * @param {object} element
         * @returns {undefined}
         */
        function reOrient(orientation, element) {
            switch (orientation) {
                case 1:
                    // No action needed
                    break;
                case 2:
                    element.css({
                        '-moz-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        '-o-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        'transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        'filter': 'FlipH',
                        '-ms-filter': "FlipH"
                    });
                    break;
                case 3:
                    element.css({
                        'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'
                    });
                    break;
                case 4:
                    element.css({
                        '-moz-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        '-o-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        'transform': 'scaleX(-1) rotate(180deg)',
                        'filter': 'FlipH',
                        '-ms-filter': "FlipH"
                    });
                    break;
                case 5:
                    element.css({
                        '-moz-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        '-o-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        'transform': 'scaleX(-1) rotate(90deg)',
                        'filter': 'FlipH',
                        '-ms-filter': "FlipH"
                    });
                    break;
                case 6:
                    element.css({
                        'transform': 'rotate(90deg)'
                    });
                    break;
                case 7:
                    element.css({
                        '-moz-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        '-o-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                        'transform': 'scaleX(-1) rotate(-90deg)',
                        'filter': 'FlipH',
                        '-ms-filter': "FlipH"
                    });
                    break;
                case 8:
                    element.css({
                        'transform': 'rotate(-90deg)'
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }// End reOrient()
    }// End orient()
})(window.angular, window.EXIF, window);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function (angular, EXIF) {
    'use strict';
angular.module("cp.ng.fix-image-orientation", []).directive('imgFixOrientation', [orient]);

/**
 * Directive definition.
 * 
 * @returns {object}
 */
function orient() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'imgFixOrientation': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('imgFixOrientation', function (imageUrl) {
                if (0 === imageUrl.indexOf('data:image')) {
                    var base64 = imageUrl.split(',')[1];
                    var exifData = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(base64ToArrayBuffer(base64));
                    reOrient(parseInt(exifData.Orientation || 1, 10), element);
                }
                else {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("GET", imageUrl, true);
                    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
                    xhr.onload = function (e) {
                        var arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(this.response);
                        var exifData = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(arrayBuffer.buffer);
                        reOrient(parseInt(exifData.Orientation || 1, 10), element);
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                }
            });


        }
    };

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * 
     * @param {object} scope
     * @param {object} element
     * @param {object} attrs
     * @returns {undefined}
     */


    /**
     * Convert base64 string to array buffer.
     * 
     * @param {string} base64
     * @returns {object}
     */
    function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
        var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
        var len = binaryString.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return bytes.buffer;
    }

    /**
     * Reorient specified element.
     * 
     * @param {number} orientation
     * @param {object} element
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function reOrient(orientation, element) {
        switch (orientation) {
            case 1:
                // No action needed
                break;
            case 2:
                element.css({
                    '-moz-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    '-o-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    'transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    'filter': 'FlipH',
                    '-ms-filter': "FlipH"
                });
                break;
            case 3:
                element.css({
                    'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'
                });
                break;
            case 4:
                element.css({
                    '-moz-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    '-o-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    'transform': 'scaleX(-1) rotate(180deg)',
                    'filter': 'FlipH',
                    '-ms-filter': "FlipH"
                });
                break;
            case 5:
                element.css({
                    '-moz-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    '-o-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    'transform': 'scaleX(-1) rotate(90deg)',
                    'filter': 'FlipH',
                    '-ms-filter': "FlipH"
                });
                break;
            case 6:
                element.css({
                    'transform': 'rotate(90deg)'
                });
                break;
            case 7:
                element.css({
                    '-moz-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    '-o-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(-1)',
                    'transform': 'scaleX(-1) rotate(-90deg)',
                    'filter': 'FlipH',
                    '-ms-filter': "FlipH"
                });
                break;
            case 8:
                element.css({
                    'transform': 'rotate(-90deg)'
                });
                break;
        }
    }// End reOrient()
}// End orient()
})(window.angular, window.EXIF, window);
```

Comment: It's not triggering when value change in img-fix-orientation attribute

Comment: I updated code please try now . Hope it ll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using ng-if to trigger your template after loading imageUrl as like below,

```
<img img-fix-orientation="imageUrl" ng-if="imageUrl" ng-src="{{ imageUrl }}">
```

you can also do

```
 <img img-fix-orientation="imageUrl" ng-if="imageUrl" ng-src="{{:: imageUrl }}">
```

for [one time binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201325/what-does-mean-in-angularjs)

Comment: It only hide the image.